# Connect a USB slave into Arduino using FTDI

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, ftdi

Probably I'm asking a nonsense question but I'm new at interfaces.

I want to connect an USB barcode scanner to an Arduino (Uno or Mega). I've read that I need a USB host shield to achieve this. But I don't have any. I have a FTDI, so I suppose I could plug the USB output of the scanner into the FTDI and connect the FTDI to the UART port of Arduino. Then, I would be passing the USB output to Serial.

Is it correct? Thanks and sorry if I said something stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is completely wrong.

In USB you have *hosts* and *devices*. A *device* has to connect to a *host*. Your FT232 is a *device*. The barcode scanner is a *device*. Both of them need to be connected to a *host* for them to do anything.

So you need a USB *host* shield to act as that host.

However - check the manual for your barcode scanner: it may well have a RS-232 mode that it can be switched into (may need a different cable attached).

Comment: Okay thanks! Yes, RS-232 was my second option. I need extra hardware apart from the cable, don't I?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It depends on your barcode scanner. Read the manual - see what it says.